# Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x1055952b0) to 'NSString' (0x1023e3c60)

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3, imdb

I am using http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=pulp+fiction IMDB api for "pulp fiction" in my Code.

There is a search bar in the application and I write "pulp fiction" to this search bar then enter. 
I get this error.

> Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x1055952b0) to
>   'NSString' (0x1023e3c60).

ViewController.swift:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  IMDB Api Project
//
//  Created by gurkan on 5.05.2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 gurkan. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var directorLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ratingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var actorsLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchForMovie(title: searchBar.text!)
        searchBar.text = ""
    }

    func searchForMovie(title: String){
        //http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=pulp+fiction
        if let movie = title.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed){
            let url = URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=\(movie)")
            let session = URLSession.shared
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                } else {
                    if data != nil {
                        do {
                            let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
                                as! String //Error Line!

                            let jsonString = jsonResult.components(separatedBy: "")

                            let jsonDict = jsonString as! Dictionary<String,String>

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                print(jsonDict)
                            }
                        } catch {
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your JSON is a dictionary, not a string.

Comment: I tried as if dictionary but I get error before. So how to solve? what is the all code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two things wrong.

First, this line force unwraps to a `String`

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
                            as! String
```

Simple remove `as! String` - it's not needed. Swift will infer the type and correctly create `jsonResult`.

Second, your code assumes that the JSON response coming back is a dictionary made up entirely of `String` names, and `String` values. Looking at the response from the url you posted, the object associated with the `Ratings` value is actually a dictionary. Since you are force unwrapping `jsonString` into a dictionary of strings, that will fail, since it is NOT a dictionary of strings.  It's a dictionary of Strings and other stuff - a dictionary.

The easiest fix is:

Replace this line:

```
let jsonDict = jsonString as! Dictionary<String,String>
```

with

```
let jsonDict = jsonString as! [String: AnyObject]
```

Comment: I am getting same error in this line. 
Problematic line is : 
                            let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
                                as! String 
So I think we should change this line.

Comment: oh yes , remove "as! String" as well

Comment: I am getting this error when make it comment(remove) "as! String"
https://i.hizliresim.com/z3N2W4.png

Comment: remove that line too, not needed

Comment: I updated my code with your edited answer but I am getting same error still. 
Before clicking red 
https://i.hizliresim.com/W0j4Zq.png
After clicking red

https://i.hizliresim.com/r3Gjgz.png

Comment: the "components separated by" line is not needed